# Reading file data from shared folder with authentication (FileNotFound Exception)

Tags: java, csv, file-io

Following is the code I use to access file from a share folde by authenticating and reading data from the file.(using JCIFs)

```
public void findFiles() throws Exception{
         String url = rs.getString("addPolicyBatchFolder_login_url"); //username, url, password are specified in the property file
         String username = rs.getString("addPolicyBatchFolder_login_userName");
         String password = rs.getString("addPolicyBatchFolder_login_password");
         NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, username, password);

         SmbFile dir = null;
         dir = new SmbFile(url, auth);
         SmbFilenameFilter filter = new SmbFilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(SmbFile dir, String name) throws SmbException {
                    return name.startsWith("starting string of file name");//picking files which has this string on the file name
                }
            };

         for (SmbFile f : dir.listFiles(filter))
         {

             addPolicyBatch(f.getCanonicalPath()); //passing file path to another method

         }
}
```

With this code, I'm successfully authenticating and I'm able to list the files. And I tried printing canonical path(i tried with just `f.path()` also) and im able to print the complete path.

Following is the next method.

```
public void addPolicyBatch(String filename) throws Exception{
    File csvFile = new File(filename);
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile)); //FileNotFound exception
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ 
                    //more code
```

In the above method, when it comes to bufferReader, its showing `FleNotFoundException`.

If I print the canonical path, following is the output.

`smb://sharePath/file.csv`   **correct path**

But in the second method(where I get Exception), the exception is as follows.

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: smb:\sharePath\file.csv (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`

As you can see, there is only one `\` after `smb:`.

I'm not sure why its not passing the exact file path as printed in the first method.

Comment: Well, the Exception already points that your path is incorrect. Try to use different variations of path, e. g. with double backslashes

Comment: I've tried couple of ways. `smb:///`, `smb://`. Even so, if Im able to list the files with proper path, how would it go wrong in the next method ?

Comment: try other possibilities. I can't say which one is the right as I can't test it right now, but as the exception shows you the path with the backslashes, then I would also try it with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the leading `smb:` from the name it should work.
Alternatively, you can change your method as follows and use the smb file to create a reader:

```
public void addPolicyBatch(SmbFile smbFile) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        SmbFileInputStream smbStream = new SmbFileInputStream(smbFile); 
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(smbStream)); 
        String line; 
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ 
        //....
```

**Edit**, renaming a file.

If you want to use SmbFile to rename, you need the authentication object

```
public static void renameSmbFile(SmbFile srcFile, String completeUrl, 
                                 NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth) throws Exception {
    SmbFile newFile = new SmbFile(completeUrl,auth);
    srcFile.renameTo(newFile);
}
```

Wenn using a File object, that is not neccessary:

```
public static void renameFile(SmbFile srcFile, String nameWithoutProtocol, 
                              NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth) throws Exception {
    String fileName = srcFile.getCanonicalPath();
    fileName = fileName.substring(4);//removing smb-protocol
    new File(fileName).renameTo(new File(nameWithoutProtocol));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the work. One more doubt. I tried to rename the file after reading. I'm not able to pass new name string to the `renameTo` method. So i tried creating a new file(new name) and copy the contents. Is this correct, or can I do it first way ?